# Tor browser not opening from Tails

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, tails, proxy, connection

After I have installed Tails I tried to open Tor browser from Tails but first I got the message that Tor browser was not yet ready. After I tried to open it anyway (as the option is provided) I got the following message:

The proxy server is refusing connections.
Firefox is configured to use a proxy server that is refusing connections.
- Check the proxy settings to make sure that they are correct
- Contact your network administrator to make sure the proxy server is working

I have no Firefox installed on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

> The proxy server is refusing connections. Firefox is configured to use a proxy server that is refusing connections. - Check the proxy settings to make sure that they are correct

This message means that you are not connected to a network, you can find the required information on [this page of the documentation](https://tails.boum.org/doc/anonymous_internet/networkmanager)

> I have no Firefox installed on my computer.

Yes it's misleading but in this message "Firefox" is referring to the web-browser shipped in Tails, the Tor Browser (which is based on Firefox)